# TypeScript Compiler API function which can check if a class implements an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I wanted to check whether a `ClassDeclaration` of a file `a.ts` implements an `InterfaceDeclaration` from a file `b.ts` using [Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API). But I couldn't find a method or a function for it.

```
function isClassImplementInterface(
  ts.ClassDeclaration: classDeclaration,
  ts.InterfaceDeclaration: interfaceDeclaration
): boolean {
  // return true if classDeclaration implements interfaceDeclaration correctly
}
```

Is there any function for it out of Compiler API?

Comment: You can use `checker.isTypeAssignableTo` after you get the types of the class and the interface declaration.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir that's internal API so it can't be used. See the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9879).

Comment: @DavidSherret Wops, my bad, thought that ways part of the public api

Answer (score 4):

To check if a class directly implements a certain interface you can look at the types of the implements heritage clause.

For example:

```
function doesClassDirectlyImplementInterface(
    classDec: ts.ClassDeclaration,
    interfaceDec: ts.InterfaceDeclaration,
    typeChecker: ts.TypeChecker
) {
    const implementsClause = classDec.heritageClauses
        ?.find(c => c.token === ts.SyntaxKind.ImplementsKeyword);

    for (const clauseTypeNode of implementsClause?.types ?? []) {
        const clauseType = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(clauseTypeNode);
        if (clauseType.getSymbol()?.declarations.some(d => d === interfaceDec))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You may want to expand on that to also check if the class declaration has a base class and then check that class' heritage clauses as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the above code will be a great help.
I'll try to make a utility code based on your guide.
Thanks ! :D